# Auto convert type in haskell

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, type-families

I've written some helpful functions to do logical operation. It looks like `` (a and b or c) `belongs` x ``.

Thanks to `Num`, `IsList` and `OverloadedLists`, I can have it for integers and lists.

```
λ> (1 && 2 || 3) `belongs` [2]
False
λ> (1 && 2 || 3) `belongs` [1, 2]
True
λ> (1 && 2 || 3) `belongs` [3]
True

λ> :set -XOverloadedLists
λ> ([1, 2] && [2, 3] || [3, 4]) `contains` 1
False
λ> ([1, 2] && [2, 3] || [3, 4]) `contains` 2
True
```

I do it this way:

```
newtype BoolLike a = BoolLike ((a -> Bool) -> Bool)

(&&) :: BoolLike a -> BoolLike a -> BoolLike a
BoolLike f && BoolLike g = BoolLike $ \k -> f k P.&& g k
infixr 3 &&

toBoolLike :: a -> BoolLike a
toBoolLike x = BoolLike $ \k -> k x

belongs :: Eq a => BoolLike a -> [a] -> Bool
belongs (BoolLike f) xs = f (\x -> x `elem` xs)

contains :: Eq a => BoolLike [a] -> a -> Bool
contains (BoolLike f) x = f (\xs -> x `elem` xs)

instance Num a => Num (BoolLike a) where
  fromInteger = toBoolLike . fromInteger
```

What I am going to do is make it suit for any types, without manually convert `a` to `BoolLike a`.

How can I achieve it?

First try:

```
class IsBool a where
  type BoolItem a
  toBool :: a -> BoolItem a

instance IsBool (BoolLike a) where
  type BoolItem (BoolLike a) = BoolLike a
  toBool = id

instance IsBool a where
  type BoolItem a = BoolLike a
  toBool = toBoolLike
```

Failed:

```
Conflicting family instance declarations:
  BoolItem (BoolLike a) -- Defined at BoolLike.hs:54:8
  BoolItem a -- Defined at BoolLike.hs:58:8
```

Comment: There's the [Boolean](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Boolean) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this

```
type family BoolItem a where
    BoolItem (BoolLike a) = BoolLike a
    BoolItem a = BoolLike a

class IsBool a where
  toBool :: a -> BoolItem a

instance IsBool (BoolLike a) where
  toBool = id

instance (BoolItem a ~ BoolLike a) => IsBool a where
  toBool = toBoolLike
```

By moving the type family out of the class you can define it for all types. Then all that remains is restricting one of the instances. Don't forget you'll also need to make that one `OVERLAPPABLE`

Comment: I define `&&` as `(toBool -> BoolLike f) && (toBool -> BoolLike g) = BoolLike $ \k -> f k P.&& g k`, and `||` similar.

It looks good, until `let relation = 1 && 2 || 3`, ghci cannot deduce (BoolItem a10 ~ BoolLike a3).

The full source code is https://github.com/qzchenwl/BoolLike/blob/master/src/BoolLike.hs

Comment: It's OK for `Char`. I've updated the [`Main.hs`](https://github.com/qzchenwl/BoolLike/blob/master/src/Main.hs)

Comment: @wenlong, this is because `1`, `2`, etc. have a non-monomorphic type, i.e. `Num a => a`. If the type is unambiguous, like `(1 :: Int) && (2 :: Int) || (3 :: Int)`, it works.

Comment: To expand a bit, there could potentially be a `Num` instance for `BoolLike` and then the other instance would match. There are ways around this that sometimes work and I'm currently seeing if I can find one, but annotating things is probably the cleanest option.

Comment: @wenlong I've made it work for your examples https://gist.github.com/LukaHorvat/039da8546d7f831a7f7e6348da03d089 (don't tell anyone you're using `INCOHERENT` instances)

Answer (score 3):

This answer probably won't be useful to you, as in all likelihood you have already considered the alternative I am going to suggest and deemed it not enough for your devilish purposes. Still, readers who stumble upon this question might find it useful to know how to achieve something similar to what you were looking for, if not quite as nifty, without type class trickery.

In your plans, a `BoolLike a` ...

```
newtype BoolLike a = BoolLike ((a -> Bool) -> Bool)
```

... consists of a function which produces a `Bool` result when given an `a -> Bool` continuation. Your usage examples all boil down to combining the `Bool` results with `(&&)` and `(||)` before supplying the continuation. That can be achieved using the `Applicative` instance for functions (in this case, `(->) (a -> Bool)`) and using `(&)`/`flip ($)` to promote plain values into `(a -> Bool) -> Bool` "suspended computations":

```
GHCi> ((||) <$> ((&&) <$> ($ 1) <*> ($ 2)) <*> ($ 3)) (`elem` [2])
False
```

That, of course, is not at all tidy to write. However, we can improve things quite a lot by defining:

```
(<&&>) :: Applicative f => f Bool -> f Bool -> f Bool
x <&&> y = (&&) <$> x <*> y

(<||>) :: Applicative f => f Bool -> f Bool -> f Bool
x <||> y = (||) <$> x <*> y
```

(For a little library defining them, have a look at [*control-bool*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-bool-0.2.1).)

Armed with these, the extra line noise becomes quite lightweight:

```
GHCi> (($ 1) <&&> ($ 2) <||> ($ 3)) (`elem` [2])
False
```

This works out of the box for the `contains` case as well — all that it takes is changing the supplied continuation:

```
GHCi> (($ [1, 2]) <&&> ($ [2, 3]) <||> ($ [3, 4])) (elem 1)
False
```

As a final note, it is worth pointing out the `contains` case can be straightforwardly expressed in terms of `intersect` and `union` from `Data.List`:

```
GHCi> [1, 2] `intersect` [2, 3] `union` [3, 4] & elem 1
False
```

Comment: Also worth noting that if you tag your "bottom values" as you do here with `$` it also makes the OP's problem go away since then the operators can be implemented only for `BoolLike`s and they don't have to be polymorphic.